# Hiddeln section not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this hidden section with the `display:none`. The div with the `TextBox` control is using `col-md-11` but when  switch the display this section looks like it is only taking up about `col-md-5`. Is there anything I can do to make sure this is using the correct space?

```
<div class="col-md-11 !important">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label source-label">Other</label>
     <input class="form-control" id="enteredOtherSource" name="enteredOtherSource[0].Other" type="text" value="">
     <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="enteredOtherSource[0].Other" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
     </div>
     <input value="91" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SourceId must be a number." data-val-required="The SourceId field is required." id="otherSourceId" name="enteredOtherSource[0].SourceId" type="hidden">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please show plain rendered HTML, not server-side code. See [ask]. Also, tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: `display: none` removes the element completely from the element colllection. Use `visibility: hidden` if you want the space to be reserved.

Comment: Is that the only way to reserved the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: none` causes the page to be rendered as if the element does not exist, so the space it would have occupied is filled with the next element.

To reserve space `visibility: hidden` can be used.

The working snippet below shows sets of three divs where the middle one is either removed with `display:none` or hiddent with `visibility:hidden`

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 3px;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.none {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  Three normal divs, the middle one will have a style applied to hide or make it invisible in the lower panels
  <div>1 - normal div </div>
  <div>2 - none or visibility hidden below</div>
  <div>3 - normal div </div>
</div>
<p> </p>
<div class='container'>
  When using `display:none` the div and its space disappear:
  <div>1 - normal div </div>
  <div class="none">2 - display will be none</div>
  <div>3 - normal div </div>
</div>
<p> </p>
<div class='container'>
  when using `visibility: hidden` the div disappears but its space is reserved:
  <div>1 - normal div </div>
  <div class="hidden">2 - display will be none</div>
  <div>3 - normal div </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so in js I would do somehting like `$("[id='sourceSection_" + section + "']").style.visibility = 'visible';`

Comment: To set it with javascript you'd make a reference to the element object (e.g. `document.getElementById("myHiddenDiv")` and set its style property as in your comment: `.style.visibility = 'visible'`. Getting the element by Id is simple but there are other methods such as `getElementByClassName()` and `document.querySelectorAll()`. If you use those, be aware they return an html collection of all the matching elements, and you have to define the relevant element with an index number, [0] for the first match, as if the list was an array.

Comment: I missed the plural (s) out the second reference, it should have been `getElementsByClassName()`